# Python restaurant program

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python & this is my 3rd program.
I'm learning functions. The user should be able to choose a number first from the menu (1. appetizers, 2.mains 3. drinks, 4.view orders, 5.exit) each one has sub-choices (example appetizers include salad, chips...etc). User should be able to return back after choosing an item.
I'm stuck in View Order option, the user needs to be able to see each of the items in their order + prices next to each item & Lastly I want to be able to show total bill.
How can i view all orders from user?
How can i calculate total? should i use loop?

```
def menu():
  print("--MCQUAN MENU--")
  print("1. Appetizers")
  print("2. Mains")
  print("3. Drinks")
  print("4. Desserts")
  print("5. View order")
  print("6. Exit")
  print()

def user_option():
  choice = int(input("Choose from the menu & enter a number 1-6: "))
  if choice == 1:
    print()
    print("APP - heres the apps")
    print("Salad - $5")
    print("Chips & salsa - $6")
    print("Soup - $10")
  elif choice == 2:
    print("MAINS - here the mains")
    print("Pasta - $13")
    print("Burger - $12")
    print("Pizza - $10")
  elif choice == 3:
    print("DRINKS - heres drinks")
    print("Water - $0")
    print("Tea - $3")
    print("Sprite - $2")
  elif choice == 4:
    print("DESSERTS - heres desserts")
    print("Cake - $6")
    print("Ice cream - $5 ")
    print("Pie - $7")
  elif choice == 5:
    print("VIEW ORDER -- heres ur order so far")
  elif choice == 6:
    print("Exiting")
  else:
    print("Invalid")
    choice = int(input("Enter number 1-6"))

def app():
  cost = 0
  total = 0
  user_food = input("Choose which u want ")
  if user_food == "salad":
    cheese = input("Cheese? (+$0.50) yes/no ")
    dressing = input("Dressing? (+$1) yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "chips & salsa":
    spicy = input("Spicy? yes/no ")
    cilantro = input("Cilantro? yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "soup":
    soup = input("Chicken noodle or mushroom? ")
  else:
    print("Alright!")
  user_option()
  user_food = input("Choose which u want ")

def main():
  user_food = input("Choose which u want ")
  if user_food == "pasta":
    cheese_2 = input("Cheese? yes/no ")
    chilli_f = input("Chilli flakes? yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "burger":
    onions = input("Onions? yes/no ")
    pickles = input("Pickles? yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "Pizza":
    pizza = input("Cheese or pepperoni? ")
  else:
    print("Alright!")
  user_option()
  user_food = input("Choose which u want ")

  def drinks():
    user_food = input("Choose which u want ")
    if user_food == "water":
      size = input("Small, medium or large? ")
    user_option()
    user_food = input("Choose which u want ")
  def desserts():
  user_food = input("Choose which you want")
  if user_food == "cake":
    w_c = input("Whipped cream? yes/no ")
    cherry = input("Cherry? yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "ice cream":
    w_c = input("Whipped cream? yes/no")
    cherry = input("Cherry? yes/no ")
  elif user_food == "pie":
    w_c = input("Whipped cream? yes/no")
    cherry = input("Cherry? yes/no ")
  else:
    print("Alright")
    user_option()
    user_food = input("Choose which u want ")



     
#main
menu()
print("Welcome to McQuans!")
print()
user_option()
app()
main()
drinks()
desserts()`
```

Comment: Hi! SO isn't exactly the right place for these types of question. In this case, an answer most suited to you would take into account that you are learning and would not use concepts you might not be familiar with. As a result, the real answer to "how should this be done" is not exactly the answer you would want.  As such, this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: To help you out - and again, this is highly personal and depends on what you do or do not already know - I would advice you to try to change this code to use a dictionary or lists. Currently, each menu item is held in a print statement. Can you think of a way to include all the food items, including if their type (like app, main, drinks) and price into a dictionary? If you have such a data structure, you would not need so many print statements anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you do not want to keep your data in prints.
We can use data structures like `lists` or `dicts`

Here's what I suggest:

- We use a `list` for the client order, since we can keep adding to it and we'll be adding things sequentially.
- We use `dicts` (python dictionaries) for the menus, so we can keep track of all the items per menu and the price of each item.

```py
client_order = []

app_menu = {
    "Salad": 5,
    "Chips & salsa": 6,
    "Soup": 10
}
```

Please check out this [Dict tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_loop.asp) if you are not familiar with them.

Alright, let's start with this. Once you've got it I'll help you out some more if you need.